# How to use global var in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need  to use virtual assistant from another source ( and need to use this vars

```
<script>
        var chat_client = 'big',
            chat_mode=2,
            ailabs_user_id = null,
        ailabs_user_info  = {'user_intent_category_label':'DEFAULT', 'info_fullname':'Ержанов Ануар Толегенович', 'info_iin':'921102350927', 'info_phone_number':'87473096538'};
    </script>
```

How i can use it in react and do it global var for have a oppurtunity to use it from template?
When I try to use var from Header component I have error ( is undefined )
i need to use `'info_fullname':{employee.fullname}`

Comment: why you need it?Why you can not use redux store?

Comment: i need to use it in a place where <div id="root"></div> So i can't call variables from react there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?

You can declare a global context variable in any of the parent components and this variable will be accessible across the component tree by this.context.varname. You only have to specify childContextTypes and getChildContext in the parent component and thereafter you can use/modify this from any component by just specifying contextTypes in the child component.

However, please take a note of this as mentioned in docs:

We can create global variable by using window keyword.

```
window.$name = 'king' //global variable
```

Now we can access the global variable **window.$name** from our components.

```
function App() {
  const name = window.$name;
  console.log(name); // 'king'

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access all global variables with `window.variableName`, `window` is the `global` object in the browser environment.

A better way to work with the global variable is by using it with Webpack `external` config.

[Webpack External Reference](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

Comment: Using many global variables is not a good idea that it may cause variable conflicts